# How to return real self type of subclass?

Tags: c++

I want a function return its real type, even it called in subclass. Here is the test code:

```
class Super
{
public:
    Super(){};
    virtual auto getSelf() -> decltype(*this)&
    {
        return *this;
    }
    void testSuper(){};
};

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    void testSub(){};
};

int main() 
{
    Sub().getSelf().testSuper();//OK
    //Sub().getSelf().testSub();//Error
    return 0;
}
```

In Objective-C, I can use `instanttype` to solve this.
But in C++, is it possible?

By the way, I do not want a `template` implementation, since it may increase the code size.

Comment: Why not templates? They are sometime the best solution for the problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot  The compiler will generate code for all `template` type, which make increase the code size.

Comment: Why down votes? Is there any wrong to ask this question?

Comment: And it will make your function much more faster, and the compiler can even optimize out your class completely when using template. Don't do premature optimisation on your code.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It's not premature, it's actually my problem now. Don't guess what you don't know, just solve the question itself.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I think it'a problem that can be solved by compiler time type trait. But I don't know how. So it's not necessary to use `template`.

Comment: You cannot assume that virtual polymorphism will result in a smaller binary unless you know how the compiler you use optimize your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But in C++, is it possible?

Yes, and just like anything in C++, there is many ways to do it. But both ways require you to add something in the `Sub` class.

If you don't need virtual functions, then simply override (statically) that function:

```
struct Super {
    auto getSelf() -> Super& {
        return *this;
    }

    void testSuper(){};
};

struct Sub : Super {
    auto getSelf() -> Sub& {
        return *this;
    }

    void testSub(){};
};

int main() {
    Sub().getSelf().testSuper(); //OK
    Sub().getSelf().testSub(); //OK too!
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you don't like copy pasting that code, you can always create a mixin class (a CRTP template):

```
template<typename Subclass>
struct AddGetSelf {
    auto getSelf() -> Subclass& {
        return static_cast<Subclass&>(*this);
    }
};
```

You can the use that mixin in your classes like this:

```
struct Super : AddGetSelf<Super> {
    using AddGetSelf<Super>::getSelf;

    void testSuper(){};
};

struct Sub : Super, AddGetSelf<Sub> {
    using AddGetSelf<Sub>::getSelf;

    void testSub(){};
};
```

If you need virtual polymorphism, you can rely on covariant return types:

```
struct Super {
    virtual auto getSelf() -> Super& {
        return *this;
    }

    void testSuper(){};
};

struct Sub : Super {
    auto getSelf() -> Sub& override {
        return *this;
    }

    void testSub(){};
};

int main() {
    Sub().getSelf().testSuper(); //OK
    Sub().getSelf().testSub(); //OK too!
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a live example at [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e995473c22fedba3)

If you are worried about binary size, consider static linking and link time optimisation.

I suggest you to try out both solutions and compare binary sizes, since template size increase can be cancelled out by compiler optimisation, and virtual polymorphism can prevent the compiler to do these optimisations.

Comment: Haha, funny that there are two answers 2 mins apart, one saying "yes", and the other goes with "no". Ima still say what OP wants is not possible. You provide nice and interesting workarounds though. Well... they are solutions intelligently neglecting the requirements, worth exploring.

Comment: Actually, both of these are not perfect solutions. 1 and 3 is a kind of copy and paste. 2 is also template too. But it's a different kind of thought, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Ringo_D Actually, solution 2 is the same as 1 but without manual copy-pasting.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go ahead with **no**. There is not convenient mechanisms in c++ to perform what you wish. *(By convenient I mean avoiding any boilerplate, IMO options presented by Guillaume in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41582857/1133179) are certainly worth exploring.)*

The code for different cases has to be duplicated. Types and objects cannot be created during run-time, like e.g. in C#. So you have to have code for each type.

You can do what you wish through static polymorphism, though those are templates. Maybe the compiler is smart enough to optimize each copy of `getSelf`, after all it's all returning the same pointer. But from the language point of view you have to provide a definition for each type.

There is run-time type information, but you would still need to `if` between the types effectively duplicating the code.

You might implement your example pure run-time using RTTI and dynamic cast, but it would be kinda ugly, as you would have to cast to reference manually... and dangerous.

E.g:

```
#include <iostream>
class Super
{
public:
    Super(){};
    virtual auto getSelf() -> decltype(*this)&
    {
        return *this;
    }
    void testSuper(){};
};

class Sub : public Super
{
public:
    void testSub(){std::cout << "test\n"; };
};

int main() 
{
    Sub().getSelf().testSuper();//OK
    dynamic_cast<Sub&>(Sub().getSelf()).testSub();//Danger
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But in C++, is it possible?

Short answer is - ***not directly** as it happens in C#*.
The type of `this` is the one of a pointer to the type of the subobject that offers the member function definition.
That is, `Super *` within `getSelf` definition in `Super`, `Sub *` within `getSelf` definition in `Sub`.

---

That said, note that the goal of double dispatching matches your requirements.
The *drawback* is that a call like `Sub().getSelf().method();` is not possible anymore in this case.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
struct Visitor;

struct Super
{
    virtual void getSelf(Visitor &) = 0;
    void testSuper(){}
};

struct Sub : Super
{
    void getSelf(Visitor &) override;
    void testSub(){}
};

struct Visitor
{
    void accept(Sub &sub)
    {
        sub.testSuper();
        sub.testSub();
    }
};

void Sub::getSelf(Visitor &v)
{
    v.accept(*this);
}

int main() 
{
    Visitor visitor;
    Sub sub;
    Super &super = sub;
    super.getSelf(visitor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to be done as in Object-C is not possible in C++. They have different object calling models. See [Object-C Messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages). When you call object in C++ compiler must know everything about member function at compile time. In Object-C you don't call member function directly you send message to the object. So this is run-time binding.

Comment: This is true in the "default" case, but virtual functions *are* runtime binding.

Comment: Yes, it's right. But without type casting (static or dynamic) you can't get access to non-virtual member function that is absent in source type. Virtual function seems to be a solution but you can't change its' result type. So you need dynamic type checking and type casting. It's not as symple as in Object-C but workaround.